# Insert textView dynamically in list view item

Tags: android, listview

Here in my application i want to insert `textview` in the custom `listview` adapter row dynamically. want to add in some of the rows and do not want to insert some of the rows. this text view would be none or number of its depends on my adapter value.
but how can i do it.i dont have an idea..

Here is my code of my Listview Adapter

```
package com.app.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.app.sample.bl.TripInfo;
import com.app.sample.utilities.sampleLogging;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TripListItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TripInfo> {

    private static ArrayList<TripInfo> itemDetailsrrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    String TripAdapterTag = "TAG";


    public TripListItemsAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
            ArrayList<TripInfo> results) {
        super(context, viewResourceId, results);
        this.layoutResourceId = viewResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        try {
            if (row == null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iconImage);
                holder.tvTripNumber = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvTripNumber);
                holder.tvPickupTime = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvPickupTime);
                holder.tvNumberPersons = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvNumberPersons);
                holder.tvIndexNumber = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvIndexNumber);
                holder.tripState = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.iconTripState);

                row.setTag(holder);

            }

            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

            holder.tvPickupTime
                    .setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).mPickupAdd);

            holder.tvNumberPersons.setText(String.valueOf(itemDetailsrrayList
                    .get(position).mNumPerson));
            holder.tvTripNumber.setText(String.valueOf(itemDetailsrrayList
                    .get(position).mTripNumber));

            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            holder.tvIndexNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

            switch (itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).mTripState) {

            case NOSHOW:
                holder.tripState.setImageResource(R.drawable.noshow);
                break;

            case EXECUTED:
                holder.tripState.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                break;

            case SCHEDULED:
                holder.tripState.setImageResource(R.drawable.scheduled);
                break;

            case STARTED:
                holder.tripState.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
                break;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            sampleLogging.e("Exception :", e);
        }
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTripNumber;
        TextView tvPickupTime;
        TextView tvNumberPersons;
        TextView tvIndexNumber;
        ImageView icon;
        ImageView tripState;
    }
}
```

Please any body suggest me how can i do Please suggest me some tutorials or examples.

Thanks